# Can you import a class from a sub-directory (from library.directory import subdirectory.class)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, python-import

Can you import a class from a sub-directory like `from library.directory import subdirectory.class`?

Let's take Selenium as an example. Its file structure is like this:

`selenium`

- `webdriver`

  - `support`

    - `ui`

      - wait.py (`WebDriverWait`)
    - expected_conditions.py

I know I can import them separately, in two lines, but for example, if there are many sub-directories in `support`, if `import`ing everything in `support` using `import selenium.webdriver.support` isn't feasible; if there are many more sub-directories under `webdriver` and `support` is a sub-sub-...-sub-directory, or if one is just too lazy to type it again, how can someone use `from selenium.webdriver.support import ui.WebDriverWait, expected_conditions as EC, wait`?

I tried importing that way (`from selenium.webdriver.support import ui.WebDriverWait, ...`), but got a `SyntaxError`. I also tried searching Python's [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), but I couldn't find anything related to this. Can it be `import`ed that way, and if yes, how?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can import a class from a subdirectory using the following syntax:

**from library.directory.subdirectory import MyClass**

for example
Suppose you have a library called library, and inside it, you have a directory called directory. Inside directory, there is a subdirectory called subdirectory, and within subdirectory, there is a file myfile.py containing a class called MyClass

To import MyClass from myfile.py, you would use the following import statement:

**from library.directory.subdirectory.myfile import MyClass**

Comment: Yes, I know I can `import` them separately in *2 lines*, but the question is about how to `import` both of them (`wait.py` and `expected_conditions.py`) in *1 line*.